# Is it possible to cluster data points based on multiple criteria simultaneously?

Tags: self-study, clustering, hierarchical-clustering

I have data points where x and y are its locations and it works well with the usual euclidean-based hierarchical clustering. The image below is the example (I explicitly request how many clusters I want).

[image: Example of euclidean distance clustering]

However, in each of data points, there are other informations as well, for example in the table below.

[image]

Is it possible to perform hierarchical clustering that is clustered by distance, but using secondary data as a condition? Let's say I want to stop when the number of population is > 10.

Sure there is a brute force way to check it, but I'm thinking there must be another way to do it.